# A quick way to revert words in sentence in unix?

Tags: linux, string, shell, unix, awk

I need something which reverts words in a sentence in opposite order. I am sure it is possible to do without writing a script.

Something which receives an input stream like `echo AAaa BBbb CCcc | foo` and prints `CCcc BBbb AAaa`

Sorry, I changed the example, the words themselves should not be reverted. So, rev does not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well when I saw this question, I thought tac or rev too. however I guess OP made a bad example with AAA BBB. he may want to revert "word"s but not all characters.

see this, if it is what you want:

```
kent$  echo "this is another test example"|awk '{for(i=NF;i>0;i--)printf $i" "}'
example test another is this
```

Comment: This solution works on multi-line input, but give an extra space at the end.  It can be checke with `echo "a b c" | awk '{for(i=NF;i>0;i--)printf $i" "}'  | sed -e 's/^/|/;s/$/|/'`.

Comment: Re avoiding an unwanted trailing space: `echo "a b c" | awk '{for(i=NF;i>1;i--)printf $i" "}{print $1}'` ... (use `printf $1` if you don't want the trailing `ORS`

Answer (score 5):

sure there is, its `rev`:

```
~ $ echo AAA BBB CCC DDD | rev
DDD CCC BBB AAA
~ $
```

EDIT:

Ok, so you may also try using `tac` this way:

```
~ $ echo -n "AAaa BBbb CCcc DDdd " | tac -s ' '
DDdd CCcc BBbb AAaa ~ $
```

The only problem is it doesn't display new line at the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo AAaa BBbb CCcc | tr ' ' '\n' | tac | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tac AAAA BBBB CCCC
```

Try that one!

Comment: I think you've meant 
    `echo "AAAA BBBB CCCC" | tac`
Though, for me it reverts lines not words.

Comment: @zeroos now i'am on a very old version of mac osx, so i can't directly verify it :) (old mac os's haven't cat command)

Answer (score 1):

A cryptic version usind sed, working on multi-line input, and spaces between words and at the beginning/end of the line:

```
echo -e "  AAaa     BBbb CCcc\nZ Y X" | sed -e 'G;:a;s/^\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2\n \1\3/;ta;s/\n//'
```

What it does is:

1. Append a new line at the end of the line (the `G` command),
2. Put the 1st word just after the newline (the big `s` command),
3. Loop to previous as long as there are words,
4. Remove the new line between the last word (that is now the 1st) and the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In pure bash, so without needing a subprocess, and working on multi-line input like the awk solution, but not working if many spaces between words of at the beginning/end of the line :-(:

```
function revert_line_in() {
  test $# -eq 0 && return
  test $# -eq 1 && echo -n "$1"
  test $# -eq 1 || { local word=$1; shift; revert_line_in $@; echo -n " $word"; }
}

function revert_line() {
  while read line; do revert_line_in $line; echo; done
}

echo -e "    AAaa   BBbb CCcc\nthis is another test example" | revert_line

revert_line <<< "AAaa BBbb CCcc
this is another test example"

revert_line < file
```

Note the `local` keyword in the function that declare local variable.  If omitted, the solution breaks.